# Velocity and ignoring java method return

Tags: java, return-value, velocity

I want to add an element to the list in my Velocity macro. Is this only way to avoid 'true' text appearing to the Velocity output?

```
#set($path = [])
#set($swallow = "a")

#set ($swallow = $path.add("blaablaa"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to agree with Terence Parr (father of [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)) who has relevant comments in [an Artima interview](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/stringtemplate.html) and [a good paper on model-view separation](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf).

Templates should be restricted to pure presentation. Just as we shouldn't put presentation-layer details in the model, we shouldn't put data manipulation in our templates. Doing either usually ends up making maintenance more difficult, and even makes it harder to know *where* to do the maintainance.

Based on my own experience with both Velocity and StringTemplate, I'd strongly suggest taking the problem in your question (artifacts of data manipulation making the template more complicated) as a hint and moving all manipulation of data structures into the Java layer.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, if you want to shut it up, then #set is your friend.  Many people shortcut this with a macro like this:

```
#macro( call $this )#set( $stfu = $this )#end
```

Then you can abbreviate to

```
#call( $path.add('blaablaa') )
```